# python requests module request params encoded url is different with the intended url

Tags: python, http, utf-8, python-requests, urlencode

I'm having a problem with url encoding on a python project requests module.

These are the two different url encoded params that I got from wireshark packet

> 1. 0900+%28%EB%8C%80%ED%95%9C%EB%AF%BC%EA%B5%AD+%ED%91%9C%EC%A4%80%EC%8B%9C%29
> 2. 0900%20(%EB%8C%80%ED%95%9C%EB%AF%BC%EA%B5%AD%20%ED%91%9C%EC%A4%80%EC%8B%9C)

'1' is the python requests module encoded url and '2' is the url from web browser sent packet.
When I decode both of them, it shows the same utf-8 text.

Seems like handling of blank space and parentheses is different between them.
Is there a way I can change '1' to '2'?

Here are the codes I used to send request

```
_url = "http://something"
_headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/javascript',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'ko-KR',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}
_params = {
    'action': 'log',
    'datetime': '0900 (대한민국 표준시)'
    }

# This is the request part
session = requests.Session()
res = session.get(_url, headers=_headers, params=_params)
```

Comment: can you show the full code I mean how this data is passed to requests get or post method?

Comment: @VishalSingh I edited the code. I used the requests module Session object to send get and post requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually encode your `_params` to construct your **query string** and then concatenate it to your `_url`.

> You can use [**`urllib.parse.urlencode`**[Python-Docs]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) to convert
> your `_params` dictionary to a percent-encoded ASCII text string. The resulting
> string is a series of `key=value` pairs separated by `&` characters,
> where both key and value are quoted using the `quote_via` function. By
> default, [**`quote_plus()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus) is used to quote the values, which
> means spaces are quoted as a `+` character and `/` characters are
> encoded as `%2F`, which follows the standard for GET requests
> (application/x-www-form-urlencoded). An alternate function that can be
> passed as `quote_via` is [**`quote()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote), which will encode spaces
> as `%20` and not encode `/` characters. For maximum control of what is
> quoted, use `quote` and specify a value for safe.

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus, quote, urlencode
import requests

url_template = "http://something/?{}"
_headers = { ... }
_params = {"action": "log", "datetime": "0900 (대한민국 표준시)"}
_url = url_template.format(urlencode(_params, safe="()", quote_via=quote))

response = requests.get(_url, headers=_headers)
```